# Thread error can't start new thread

Tags: python

I am trying to run as many thread as possible. however I have problem here

```
C:\Python27\lib\threading.py
  _start_new_thread(self.__bootstrap, ())
thread.error: can't start new thread
```

When I call this

> class startSleep(threading.Thread):

```
import threading
import time

class startSleep(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):

        current = x 

# input of the treads
thread = input("Threads: ")

nload = 1

x = 0

# Threads
for x in xrange(thread):
    startSleep().start()
    time.sleep(0.003)
    print bcolors.BLUE + "Thread " + str(x) + " started!"
```

I want to run as many thread as possible

Comment: Did you define this class? Why won't you show us your code?

Comment: Could you please provide more of `class sleepStart`, in case the error lies within?

Comment: Hi, I've updated above code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a limit to how many threads you can start that the system can simultaneously handle, you need to either close these threads from within (by having the function you thread either finish or while loops break) or try joining the threads by creating a list of these threads and joining the list items.

```
list_of_threads.append(example)
example.start()
for thread in list_of_threads:
      thread.join()
```

Comment: Hi matsbauer, can you pls. show it on my code above? thanks! I'll set this as answers then

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to do with the code, you are running as many threads and possible + 1, and then it crashs, it is very hard to approximate the thread capacity of the system, as this varies on many different factors and differs every time you run. My system can handle between 800 and 5000 threads, depending on activity of other apps and Programms. You can only open more threads when you close old ones :)

Comment: In Linux the maximum number of threads that can be executed is defined by -> number of threads = total virtual memory / (stack size*1024*1024) . Hope that helps you understand, each thread takes up virtual memory when started, and when this is full you cannot start new ones.

Comment: Yes it will always fail, you can only maximise the number of threads by joining them, but you cannot create unlimited number of threads, thus your code needs to be modified, but I am not sure what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: Right, now what I want is to run as many threads as possible.. What you mean your code needs to be modified?

Comment: But unless you close the threads that number will always be around 900 for you

Answer (score 0):

Now assuming you want to add unlimited threads, you need functions to simply finish, this code never ends with threads -> your unlimited threads:

```
from threading import Thread

def sleeper(i):
    print(i)

i = 0

while(1):
    t = Thread(target=sleeper, args=(i,))
    t.start()
    i += 1
```

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Mine goes until 500.000 and then I quit the Programm myself

Comment: Can you go on chat?

Comment: Is it still giving you the thread.error? What value for I does the system print last?